# How do you automate text file upload daily to a Drupal Page?

Tags: files

Im trying to create a plugin, possibly through IFTTT, where i can forward an e-mail with a text attachement that will replace a current file on a Drupal page.  Has anyone had any success in automating this process?  Bascially we're getting a text file sent to us daily that we would otherwise have to manually upload to the page.

Answer (score 2):

it's much more simple, use Mailhandler

https://www.drupal.org/project/mailhandler

Mailhandler can connect your inbox and with feed you fetch the messages, so basically you need to run the feed using cron job. 
you will find all of that in the configuration of the feed and mailhandler.

Also you can map the attachment with the field where you keep your text file, I don't think there is need to create any plugins, everything you need in mailhandler & feed.